# Backbone listenTo multiple attributes firing multiple events

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-events

I have a **Model** which in the **initialize** function I have the following code:

```
this.listenTo(this, 'change:re change:read', this.patch);
```

The **patch** function looks like this:

```
patch: function(object) {
  this.save(object.changed, { patch: true });
},
```

Elsewhere in my application I may run:

```
model.set({ re: 1 });
```

or:

```
model.set({ read: new Date() });
```

both of which work perfectly, however when I call:

```
model.set({ re: 1, read: new Date() });
```

The **patch** function gets called twice and there are two round trips to the server.  I would like to keep this down to one round trip if possible.

Can anyone help with this one?

Many thanks

David

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `patch` method gets called once for the `'change:re'` event and again for the `'change:read'` event. Backbone doesn't know that you really mean "tell me if at least one of `re` or `read` changes", it just knows that you want to be told if `re` changes and told if `read` changes.

You could listen for `'change'` events and do the filtering yourself using the [`changed`](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-changed) hash:

> **changed** `model.changed`
>
> The **changed** property is the internal hash containing all the attributes that have changed since the last *set*.

Something like this:

```
this.listenTo(this, 'change', this.patch);
```

and then:

```
patch: function() {
  if('re' in this.changed || 'read' in this.changed)
    this.save(this.changed, { patch: true });
}
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/ja20z021/

Comment: Thanks very much, seems obvious now! ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You can debouce the patch function using `_.debounce`, like so:

`this.listenTo(this, 'change:re change:read', this.patch);`

and then:

```
patch: _.debounce(function(object){
    this.save(object.changed, { patch: true });
},100)
```

The "100" is in milliseconds, the time your function waits before calling save(). In that time period, any number of change events can happen but the save is called only once.